# Fantasy Book involving a Child getting taught by different Wizards

Tags: story-identification, fairy

I am looking for a book I read that involved a Child who met a few different wizards who teach the child something. I remember one took him to the Faerie realm and he was taken through a Market where a vendor accused him of stealing an item but was found out the vendor was lying so the boy was able to pick something out of the vendors items and the child picked an egg that turned out to contain a universe inside that he traded with I believe to be the queen of the faeries because he ate something while there.

Comment: Des, when did you read this book, letting us know if it was out before X year helps

Comment: I didn't state because I don't recall when I read it I am 33 years old and I have read it between 23 years and possibly a few years ago. So between 1990 and 2013. Sorry I really do not know when I read this book because I read so many books they all merge into one sometimes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost certainly the [Books of Magic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Books_of_Magic) comic series by Neil Gaiman.

> a Child who met a few different wizards who teach the child something.

The hero, Tim Hunter, meets a different magical DC character in each of the four episodes: The Phantom Stranger, John Constantine, Dr Occult and Mr E.  They introduce him to the world of magic.

The plot elements come from Book III: The Land of Summer's Twilight.

> I remember one took him to the Faerie realm and he was taken through a
>   Market where a vendor accused him of stealing an item but was found
>   out the vendor was lying so the boy was able to pick something out of
>   the vendors items and the child picked an egg

Dr Occult takes Tim to Faerie and an imp tries to plant a bracelet on him.  When the imp is found out, the market warden lets Tim and his two companions each choose an item from the imp's barrow.  Tim chooses an egg.

> that turned out to contain a universe inside that he traded with I
>   believe to be the queen of the faeries because he ate something while
>   there.

Almost.  Tim accidentally accepts a gift from the Faerie Queen.  He can't leave Faerie until he gives her a gift of equal value.  Fortunately the egg turns out to be an egg that will one day hatch a world, which is equivalent to the gift from the Queen and gets him out of Faerie.

Comment: Thank you Looking at that it was the adapted Novels because I never read any of the comics.

Comment: I had no idea there were novelizations.  Based on the reviews, if you want to read it again I'd recommend picking up the comics instead.  They're excellent.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the comics book "Books of Magic" by Neil Gaiman.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Books_of_Magic

Comment: Could you give a little more detail about this work, e.g. by quoting from the Wikipedia page you link to? Link-only answers tend to be discouraged here, as if the link dies, the answer is rendered essentially useless.

Comment: Thank you it wasn't the comic books but the adapted Novels that I had read but the comics look interesting.

Comment: Sorry, that was my first answer. I'll try to do better next time :)